# Are particles that are moving at the fermi energy easier to remove if you model a nucleus as a fermi gas?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fermions, gas

Due to the Pauli exclusion principle, the nucleons build up the energy states from the bottom up.

When talking about binding energy per nucleon, you are talking about how much energy is needed to remove 1 nucleon.

Next, calculate the fermi energy of the nucleons. From this you can calculate the depth of the potential by finding the range of the fermi energy and binding energy.

But to do this calculation, aren't you averaging the binding energy per nucleon and then using that to find the range. Wouldn't the nucleons near the fermi energy be easier to remove from the nucleus, as they have more total energy?

Comment: I've removed some comments about a now-fixed typo and a derail about whether the typo was pointed out and fixed politely.  When in doubt, please be polite rather than defensive.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of binding energy per nucleon as a concept is not to work out the energy needed to remove one nucleon. When one nucleus fissions to two or two fuse to one, and the numbers of protons and neutrons are both conserved, whether the process is energetically favoured comes down to whether the total binding energy rises. This comparison can be replaced with one between per-nucleon values; for the one-nucleus end of the reaction this is the BEPN of that nucleus, whereas for the two-nuclei end it's a weighted mean of the BEPN of those nuclei. If fission is favoured, at least one daughter nucleus must have higher BEPN than the parent; if fusion is favoured, at least one parent nucleus must have lower BEPN than the daughter.